# "Do you want to...." as an idiom for "Can you please do this?"

Tags: idioms, questions

My husband and I disagree over my use of the phrase "Do you want to ..." when I'm asking him to please do something for me, for example "Do you want to sweep the floor while I do the dishes?" or "Do you want to hand me that Coke?"

To me it's an idiom that carries the meaning of asking him to do me a favor, but he's not familiar with this and it sounds to him like I'm literally asking whether he wants to do the thing. So I'm trying to figure out if this is a real, known idiom, or simply a weird turn of phrase I or my family developed somewhere (it's possible - I'm autistic and my family is pretty unusual).

Is anyone here familiar with this usage?

Comment: “Would you please . . “ is conventional and polite.

Comment: My grandmother said this. It would not stick out to me at all, but having said that I don't think I've heard it for a while.

Comment: Very common indeed in British English. [ However, it can be really annoying when you very specifically *don't* want to do that thing ;-)  ]

Comment: Also widespread in the US.  I agree with @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. that it's annoying in the instance he/she cites, and would likely go further.

Comment: I understand how the phrase might be used the way you intended if context is clear as in your examples. But I also understand your husband's reaction. I don't think he doesn't understand what you mean by the phrase in context. Even though he does understand what you mean, he still objects to your using the phrase as a request because it can also be understood literally. Therefore I conclude that it's not an idiom.  If it were, the literal interpretation wouldn't be so obvious.

Comment: This is a thing I commonly do in the workplace, as a more polite way of telling my coworkers to get back on task. I would not use this in my personal life, as it is a far less polite way of asking "Would you please do me a favor?"

Comment: Years ago, I worked a job where my supervisor used this construction regularly, and it always grated on my nerves. _Why doesn't he just ask me to do something instead of asking if I __want__ to do it?_ I would think.

Comment: @pook Do you speak any other languages by the way? It is common to use "Do you want to..." in this manner in some languages.

Comment: This isn't an idiom. It's a politeness mechanism.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Very true, definitely a British idiom if not an American one as well. If you don't want to do but will do it to please the other person you can say "Not really but I will"

Comment: It’s used in SE US as well. It is a thing. I’ve heard it all my life.

Comment: Common (and well understood) in Australia too, and pronounced "j'wanna". Good for when "would you please" sounds a bit *too* polite. :-)

Comment: Googled this asi find it happening more and more in the workplace. I find it *less* polite thank asking directly. Like, why do you need to resort to a 'more polite' way of asking than 'please can you...' ? If you're really asking for an opinion then say 'what do think about ...'?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rhetorical device. The intent is to ask the other person to do something, and it would often be rude for them to refuse, phrasing it this way makes it seem less like assigning or ordering them to do it.

As in one of the comments, this wording is often used when the speaker is volunteering to do some other task. The participants in the conversation are often partners, colleagues, etc. and it's normal to divide the tasks. So they're suggesting who should do each task. It would be inappropriate for one to do work while the other does nothing -- the best they can do if they don't want to do the offered task is to suggest swapping roles, e.g.

> A: I'll wash the dishes, do you want to dry them?
> B: No, I'll wash, you can dry.

This works best when the responder is actually taking on the more bothersome task. This is getting more into the purview of [Interpersonal.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com)